# Get all elements within using d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to d3.js and am trying to get an array of all the elements in the selectAll and get the reaction-label label text, for each reaction element. Below is my html and my code to access the elements:

```
    HTML: 
   <g id='reactions'>
     <g id='r0' class='reaction'>
       <g class='reaction-label-group' transform='translate(360,500)'>
         <text class='reaction-label label'>HELLO</text>
       <g id='r1' class='reaction'>
         <g class='reaction-label-group' transform='translate(365,500)'>
           <text class='reaction-label label'>HELLO2</text>


Javascript:
var reactionsVar =d3.selectAll('#reactions').selectAll('.reaction').attr("transform").text;
```

However, I am unable to get all the reaction data.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `var reactionsVar =d3.selectAll('#reactions').selectAll('.reaction').selectAll('text')[0];

console.log(reactionsVar);`

Comment: Ryan, thank you for the response. That did the trick.